# How do I automate Chrome using WatiN?

Tags: google-chrome, watin, browser-automation

I've done countless Google searches on this.

Despite all the promises, I simply can't find one straight-forward peice of documentation on how to automate Chrome with WatiN.

Can anyone help?

Comment: WatiN apparently supports Chrome, at least, experimentally. From the WatiN website: "I would like to thank my fellow committers for their work ... Edward Wild for his initial work on Firefox (and adding still expirimentel Chrome support)."

Answer (score 1):

You can better use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). It's mature, stable and has excellent browser support.